# How to rerender and refetch a component after a fetch POST in Nextjs App Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

I have a page that has a list, where you change the selected option and click save, this triggers a mutation (in this case a fetch with the POST method that changes this selection in the database). I'm trying to do it this way, but it doesn't work, it shows that the data has changed, but the component doesn't change. (I'm using Nextjs 13.4 app router).

While debugging, I found that the data changes and the "SomeComponent" component render function is called with this changed data. I can't understand, maybe it's a cache problem?

```
const Page = () => {
/* ... */
 const [data, setData] = useState(null);
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
 useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, []);

  const handleAction = useCallback(async (name, type, params) => {
    const response = await fetch("[path to post]", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ type: name, params }),
      cache: "no-store",
    })
    loadData();
  }, []);

  const loadData = useCallback(async () => {
    await fetch("path to get]", {
      method: "GET",
      cache: "no-store",
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  });

 return <SomeComponent data={data}/>

}
```

Comment: A [mcve] would be good. I would add catch blocks to all your fetch calls, and also log if `!response.ok`. Right now, there's no error handling at all. Not the problem, but combining `await` and `then` is confusing.

Comment: Since my question is in relation to rendering and performing "mutations", I thought there was something wrong with the way I was building this logic. So are you saying that depending only on the code I posted it should work, or not? If that's not the case, then I can build a reproducible example.

Comment: That's correct, based on the code here there is no obvious problem as far as I can tell. This design is a little bit unusual, though--usually when an API updates a resource, it also returns it so the front end can use the updated record rather than requiring it to run another GET. The other common approach is for the front end to optimistically apply the update from its memory and assume it worked on the BE unless it returns an error.

Comment: I put the query function (fetch "GET") inside a async "query" function then called it with useEffect to render the component the first time, then called it again inside the useCallBack that implements the fetch "POST" (mutation). It works fine but seams really strange. Do you have any tips for building a design for this type of page, the layout is fixed, only the content will be reloaded and fetched again after mutations. This is my first time with NextJs, so I'm a little lost on not having to use a GraphQL-like API that forces you to have a certain pattern.

Comment: It's common to move `fetch` calls out to a service or hook that abstracts away the nitty gritty details, but both patterns are acceptable and normal ways of fetching data in React. How you might abstract it out exactly depends on your specific application needs.